# pushing changes to git

Tags: git

I need to commit my changes (new files) to the existing master branch. However, end up creating a new branch

I have a directory structure on git as

```
master -> Projects -> Proj1 -> folder1
```

I do a

```
git clone

git branch master
git checkout master
```

I add new folders to Proj 1.

Local git structure becomes

```
master -> Projects -> Proj1 -> folder1 -> folder2 -> file1
                                                  -> file2
```

Now i do a

```
git add 
git commit -m ""
```

When i do a `git push origin Projects`, it creates a new branch Projects

```
master -> Projects -> Proj1 -> folder1 -> folder2 -> file1
                                                  -> file2
Projects -> Proj1 -> folder1 -> folder2 -> file1
                                        -> file2
```

How can i prevent creating a new branch?

will `git push origin master` do the trick?

Comment: `git push origin Projects` is *exactly* for creating a new branch named “Projects”, so if this isn’t what you wanted, you’re using the wrong command. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to commit my changes to master

Comment: You already committed them when you typed “git commit”.

Comment: It does not reflect after commit. It is a remote repository where i want to update my new files

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “reflect”.  Also, really, `git push origin Projects` shouldn’t create a new local branch (at least not with my settings), so at some point you must’ve created that branch locally. But it will push that local branch to the remote named “origin”.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the concept of "local/remote copy" and "commits". `git commit` only saves the changes to your local "master", "git push" will push that change on local copy to remote copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want push your changes into branch master you must do

```
git push origin master
```

Because name after origin is the name of your branch you want to push. So if you doing git push origin Projects You are pushing to branch "Projects"
If You want add new file to project You must do

```
git add filename
git commit -am "new filename"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `git push origin master`, or just `git push`. In general, `git push` takes the form `git push <remote> <branch>`.